# Get specific localized dates in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

Given a specific date I am looking for a way to get 12:00:00am and 11:59:59pm local time. The problem I have run into is that either one of the two is off by a day depending on which side of UTC they are on. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting 12:00:00am local time is very straightforward:

```
var dt = new Date();
dt.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Those multiple arguments look quite odd, but `setHours` accepts hours and optionally minutes, seconds, and milliseconds.

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";

  var dt = new Date();
  dt.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  display(dt);

  function display(msg) {
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    p.innerHTML = String(msg);
    document.body.appendChild(p);
  }
})();
```

Getting 11:59:59pm local time is similar:

```
var dt = new Date();
dt.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999); // 999 = ms
```

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";

  var dt = new Date();
  dt.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999); // 999 = ms
  display(dt);

  function display(msg) {
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    p.innerHTML = String(msg);
    document.body.appendChild(p);
  }
})();
```

Comment: See I should have just tried it in console. It works there, I appear to be having some other problem